# Failed to make my own drawing widget on java

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I have stucked to 4 lines of code.
They supposed to let me create my own widget.

But it seems that the `main` method is missing.

I have tried to write a main class on my-own and create an object in `paintComponent()` method with no luck.

I know that i am not supposed to call the method myself, but when i run the program i get the error Main method not found in class....

Can someone please explain me how this works or give me a link to read?

Here is the simple code that I tried:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.fillRect(20, 50, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this simple code, it should be helpful to you:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final int WIDE = 300;
    private static final int HIGH = 200;


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.fillRect(20, 50, 100, 100);
    }

    public MyDrawPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.white);
        // Set a initial size for the program window
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDE, HIGH));
    }

     private void display() {
        // Some statements to let the JFrame appear in a good way
        JFrame f = new JFrame("MyDrawPanel");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

     // Main method is called when the program is runned
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MyDrawPanel().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you that actually worked..!
A lot of unknown stuff thow.. I will try to decrypt them :) ..
Thank you very much.!

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to java,  I would suggest to just give 4-5 days on [Tutorials | Javatpoint](http://www.javatpoint.com).

Java rule is that the java file name should match the class name containing main method.

So a simple code of main method:

```
class Simple {  
    public static void main(String args[]) {  
    System.out.println("Hello Java");  
    }  
}
```

In this case this code should be in Simple.java file.

Comment: I am learning from a book, Head First Java, 2nd Edition it's called and its actually pretty good.

I had no problem until now. But the thing is that the book gives me just the above lines of code.
I tried to create main, as you say and then call
MyDrawPanel 
but it dint worked :/

Comment: Ok, that's good. I hope you resolved your query. And if yes then make sure to mark the answer as accepted as well.